# rails 3 - strftime is outputting the same time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following:

```
<% @comments.reverse.each do |comment| %>
   <%= comment.created_at.strftime("%b %d, %Y at %l:%m %p") %><
<% end %>
```

For an unknown reason the time being outputted in the loop is identical for every entry?

**Example:**

- Dec 01, 2010 at 1:12 PM
- Dec 01, 2010 at 1:12 PM
- Dec 01, 2010 at 1:12 PM
- Dec 01, 2010 at 1:12 PM

But if I change it to:

```
<% @comments.reverse.each do |comment| %>
   <%= comment.created_at %><
<% end %>
```

If outputs the correct raw timestamps, just not pretty. Any ideas here?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you are using the wrong formats to display. for example %m is month and not minute. Minute is actually %M

Here is a good reference for what to use:
http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Time.html#M000298